# Increase font size of the autocomplete dropdown in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to Increase font size of the autocomplete dropdown in visual studio - which is the area highlighted in the red box in the following screenshot. How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are actually two areas which you can configure independently. According to [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2005/09/28/how-to-change-the-font-and-font-size-for-intellisense-statement-completion-parameter-info-and-quick-tips.aspx?Redirected=true),

To change settings:

1. Go to Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors
2. Under Show settings for: select either Statement Completion or Editor Tooltips
   (for Parameter Info and Quick Tips)
3. Change either the font or font
   size

I do not have access to earlier version of Visual Studio right now but this seems to work in both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I have included some screenshots to help you.

For the actual autocomplete:

[image: Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors]

[image: Result of the change in Visual Studio 2012]

For the tooltip:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of service, Sagar :)

Comment: After that, you may need to restart Visual Studio to see affected changes.